# How to add autoscaling role and rules in AWS EMR via terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-emr, autoscaling

Has anyone succeeded in implementing Autoscale Role and rules in AWS EMR using terraform?
I wanted to simple cpu utilization rule.
But unfortunately I am not able to add Autoscale Role in generated EMR. adding rule is next step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add an auto-scaling role to an existing cluster.

- [Using Automatic Scaling in Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-automatic-scaling.html)

> When you create a cluster with an automatic scaling policy using the AWS CLI, you must first ensure that either the default IAM role exists, or that you have a custom IAM role with a policy attached that provides the appropriate permissions. To create the default role, you can run the [create-default-roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/create-default-roles.html) command before you create a cluster.
>  You can then specify --auto-scaling-role EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole option **when you create a cluster**. Alternatively, you can create a custom automatic scaling role and then specify it **when you create a cluster**, for example --auto-scaling-role MyEMRAutoScalingRole.

Please use autoscaling_policy and autoscaling_role attributes of [Resource: aws_emr_cluster](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_cluster.html).

> Automatic scaling in Amazon EMR requires an IAM role with permissions to add and terminate instances when scaling activities are triggered. **A default role configured with the appropriate role policy and trust policy, EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole, is available for this purpose**.

Comment: I am looking solution for terraform, like how to add role and rules in terraform script for AWS EMR.

Comment: Using autoscaling_policy and autoscaling_role attributes of Resource: aws_emr_cluster, that is the solution. Are you are asking how to use these attributes?

Comment: I got it thanks.. link you have provided has the correct guidelines. Thanks

Comment: any way for set this on stepfunctions ?